# Cloudinary: cloudinary_url() method fallback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Is there a fallback option when using `cloudinary_url()` if Cloudinary is unavailable (such as when working in dev offline)?

In this particular case, I've uploaded my static assets to Cloudinary and am using `cloudinary_url` in my css to pull in the background image. e.g.:

```
background-image: cloudinary_url("background.jpg");
```

However if Cloudinary is unavailable, I would like this to fallback to `/assets/images/background.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary's Ruby GEM allows to easy deliver static images of Rails applications (with or without Asset Pipeline).
You can control whether the image will be fetched from Cloudinary or locally, using the `static_image_support`  flag in `cloudinary.yml`

Here's some more information with explanation on how to use static assets with Cloudinary:
http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_deliver_your_static_images_through_a_cdn_in_ruby_on_rails